# Teaching Postgres how to handle an update on a view's column which is a result of a `case` operation

Tags: postgresql, view, triggers

I have a situation where I create a `view` based on a **single** table from a different schema (for the sake of brevity, I've shortened the example):

```sql
create view b.users as
    select
    uid as id
    case
        when name = '' then null
       else name
    end as username
from public.users;
```

Since the `username` column in the view is not a simple map I can't just update the column:

```
update b.users set username = 'foo' where id = 1234;
```

The query above results in an error.

Is there any way I can tell Postgres how to handle an update on the `username` column? Ideally, it would just insert the raw data (pseudo code):

```
create trigger handle_username_update before update
on users for each row
b.users.username = NEW.username where b.users.id = NEW.id
```

#### Edit

I will elaborate a little more to be more specific about my question.

Just as `a_horse_with_no_name` and many googling around answers suggested, I could just write a trigger to "hijack" the update operation and handle the update/insert myself. while it's possible, I would like to avoid this solution since in my case, I'm talking about potentially tens or hundreds of columns which most of them are updatable by default with a few of them that are formatted using case operations. With that solution, I would need to override the default behavior for each column. Also, each time I add a new column I will need to remember to update the trigger or else some of my applications will just stop working.

I was wondering if there any other solution for that problem.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the case expression can be simplified to `nullif(name, '') as name`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name great idea using the `nullif`! the `username` is just a single column in this view which normalizes many more columns. We have a single dataset that few applications are using. Since some applications expects the data to be in a certain format, we use views to do that